# Links to HTML bookmarks require double click to work

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create a one page site where all the different pages are located at a different section of the page. The diagram below shows what I mean...

[image: The layout of the page - note center right is mislabelled]

When a link is clicked which refers to an ID bookmark on each section it will move into view with the :target selector. The CSS is pretty basic - the page starts by placing each section at a top and left position relative to the starting view-port, and setting all height and width to 100vh or 100vw respectively.

```
.window {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    transition: top 1s, left 1s, opacity .5s;
    padding-top: 7rem;
    color: orangered;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

When a navigation link is clicked this css triggers:

```
.window:target {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

to put the window in view (with a z-index: -10 on the mid-center so it is always at the bottom, quick fix for now).

Each section has its own little piece of code to place it, i.e.:

```
.window__bot-right {
    background-color: #fff;
    top: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    color: black;
}
```

The problem is some windows dont work correctly when clicked - but if you click the link two times it works.

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/bogomip/pen/PobVZJY

Mostly the left and center ones work fine, every time. Its the ones on the right which seems to struggle unless clicked twice.

Comment: Seems to work fine without the `transition` so I'm guessing there's some kind of interference between that and `:target`.

Comment: Hmm, good spot - that does seem to work if transition goes away. Not managing to find any literature on why that might be happening but ill experiment.

Comment: what does your browser console tell you?

Comment: Browser console has no comments...